# Create image from parent picturebox graphics (not background image)

Tags: vb.net

**Edit:** I have been somewhat successful and think this may not work.  Currently this flickers badly, with the Panel1 being Refreshed() in my loop, but that is not an issue and can be fixed in a later render method.  Doing away with the custom control, and bypassing the opacity stuff, I am using the following in a basic panels paint event that is on the main form:

```
Dim tempImage = New Bitmap(Picturebox1.Width, Picturebox1.Height)
Dim memoryGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tempImage)
Dim screenPos As Point = Picturebox1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(screenPos.X, screenPos.Y, 0, 0, Picturebox1.Size)

Dim destRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
Dim srcRect As New Rectangle(picscreen.Location.X, picscreen.Location.Y, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
e.Graphics.DrawImage(tempImage, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
```

On my form: Picturebox1.Location(208, 0) & Panel1.Location(208, 0).  Both of the controls parent has to be the main form, and I cannot assign the Panel1's parent to be the Picturebox1.

The idea is to have a half-transparent panel display over the map (Picturebox1 graphics).  With the above code I am displaying an offset of what is drawn to the Panel1, from what is drawn to the Picturebox1, by about 208 pixels (or the left location of both controls).

I can adjust certain points in the code slightly to reduce the offset, but this will start showing the gray background of the Panel1 that is on the Picturebox1: [i.e Dim srcRect As New Rectangle(picscreen.Location.X - 100...] will give me 100 pixels of gray from Panel 1, and show 100 pixels closer to being lined up...going more makes the full gray Panel1 background color appear instead:

[image: Temp]

Because it is getting the image from what is all on the Picturebox1, it is also getting the Panel1 as well instead of what is underneath it.  I do not believe what I am trying to do is going to be possible

Comment: Hard to guess what "opacity effect" might mean.  Just don't use the Panel, use the picturebox' Paint event to achieve the same effect.  Set the Graphics.CompositingMode property and draw with, say, Graphics.FillRectangle().

Comment: Because the graphics are drawn on the picturebox it does not have an image or background image, only the graphics drawn to it.  The panel holds additional controls in it.  I am not sure that I would be able to draw the fake panel with opacity either, then place all the controls.

Comment: what is the role of the picturebox in all this?  how the the stuff constantly drawn applied to the PB?

Comment: The picturebox is a RenderWindow using SFML to draw a tile map for a game.  I'm drawing to the picturebox during every loop.  I created a custom panel to house other controls that uses the above code.  This works for any background image, but this does not work for the image being drawn, and everything I successfully draw only renders to black background color of the picturebox.  I probably need to go about this another way but I do not know a different way to approach it.  What other information would be helpful?

Comment: I have had a partial success, but think this may not be possible.  I have edited the original post with what I am currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the device context of both picbox and panel and bitblt the portion of picbox you want to panel:

```
<DllImport("GDI32", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function BitBlt( _
    ByVal hdcDest As IntPtr, _
    ByVal nXDest As Integer, _
    ByVal nYDest As Integer, _
    ByVal nWidth As Integer, _
    ByVal nHeight As Integer, _
    ByVal hdcSrc As IntPtr, _
    ByVal nXSrc As Integer, _
    ByVal nYSrc As Integer, _
    ByVal dwRop As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

Const SRCCOPY As Integer = &HCC0020

Dim picboxGraphics As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
Dim pnlGraphics As Graphics = Panel1.CreateGraphics
Dim PictureBox_HDC As IntPtr = picboxGraphics.GetHdc
Dim Panel_HDC As IntPtr = pnlGraphics.GetHdc
BitBlt(Panel_HDC, 0, 0, 200, 200, PictureBox_HDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) '0, 200 are arbitrary

picboxGraphics.ReleaseHdc(PictureBox_HDC)
pnlGraphics.ReleaseHdc(Panel_HDC)
picboxGraphics.Dispose()
pnlGraphics.Dispose()
```

Comment: This will work when I set the panels parent to the main form, it will display all the controls underneath it.  This does not work when I set the parent to the picturebox where the contents are constantly drawn, it only displays the original backcolor (black) of the picturebox.